# Likelihood for a random hash function not to be surjective

Tags: probability, functions, discrete-mathematics, computer-science, hash-function

Let us define a hash function $$\begin{align*}
  H \colon A &\to B\\
  a &\mapsto b
\end{align*}$$

$$|A| \geq |B|$$
Assuming it is perfectly random (Hyp 1), we estimate the probability that it is **not** surjective.
We construct a mapping
$$
  H(a_{i}) = \left\{\def\arraystretch{1.2}%
  \begin{array}{@{}c@{\quad}l@{}}
    b_{i} & \text{for } i \in \{1,...,|B|-1\} \\
    \text{any value except }\beta & \text{for } i \in \{|B|, ..., |A|\} \\
  \end{array}\right.
$$

where all but one element in B have a pre-image in A (the second part of the mapping is not explicit).

The probability that we don't hit beta after one try is
$$1 - 2^{-|B|}$$

We assume that events are independent (Hyp 2). The number of possible tries left is given by:
$$|A|-|B|+1$$

We then derive the following expression:

$$P(\text{"there exists }\beta \in B \text{ with no pre-image"}) = (1-2^{-|B|})^{|A|-|B| + 1}$$

In the case of SHA256, we have

$$
  |A| = 2^{2^{64}} \approx 2^{18446744073709551615};
  |B| = 2^{256}
$$

This gives us:
$$(1-2^{-256})^{2^{18446744073709551615}-2^{256} + 1} \leq 10^{-5000000} \approx 0$$ where the upper-bound was computed [here](http://wolfr.am/8Hmo9uaJ)

1. Is my formula correct?
2. How could I estimate this assuming a given bias in the hash function? (i.e. some values are more likely than other)

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not following your argument (why "construct" a mapping, when you want random mappings?)

I'm going to start from scratch.

If $b=|B|$ and $a=|A|$ there are at most $b(b-1)^a$ maps that miss an element - we pick an element $\beta \in B$ in $b$ ways, then pick a map from $A$ to $B\setminus \{\beta\}$ in $(b-1)^a$ ways. This over-counts maps by counting multiple times any maps that miss multiple elements, but that will tend to be a relatively tiny amount, and we have at least an upper bound for the number of such maps.

So an upper bound for our probability is: $$p<\frac{b(b-1)^a}{b^a} = b\left(1-\frac{1}{b}\right)^a$$

(This isn't a great upper bound when $a,b$ are close, since $(1-1/b)^b\approx 1/e$. But when $a$ is much larger than $b$, this is actually a useful upper bound. The value $b(1-1/b)^a$ is actually the expected number of missed elements of $B$.)

Taking the log, we get $$\log p<\log b + a\log(1-1/b)<\log b - \frac{a}{b},$$

because $\log(1-x)<-x$ for $x\in[0,1)$.

So this means the probability is less than $be^{-a/b}$, which is indeed very tiny when $a=2^{2^{64}}, b=2^{256}$ - it is bounded above by $e^{-2^{63}}$.

If the probabilities are uneven, then let $p(\beta)$ be the probability of getting $\beta\in B$, and let $p_{min}=\min_{\beta\in B} p(b)$.

Then the above argument, refactored, will show that:

$$p<b(1-p_{min})^a \leq be^{-ap_{min}}$$

Depending on how badly varied to probabilities are, this might not be a great estimate, but the $p_{min}$ value would have to be very tiny to give a significant value to $a=2^{2^{64}}$ and $b=2^{256}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I detailed my reasoning a bit more. My mapping is explicit in the first part, and implicit in the second -- I changed the wording a bit to make it clearer.

Comment: By the way, do you really have $a=2^{2^{64}}$? That seems extreme - that means your message can be $2^{64}$ bits, or $2^{21}$ terabyes.

Comment: Yes, the maximal size of input of SHA256 is specified here: http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips180-3/fips180-3_final.pdf. Thomas Pornin cites it in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658601/do-cryptographic-hash-functions-reach-each-possible-value-e-g-are-they-surject and says it is "2^64 - 1 bits"